How to Develop a Method to Forward Customer Orders
I am building a model in AnyLogic where my Sprinter agent delivers incoming customer orders from the Depot agent to the Transshipment agent. The goal is to forward the customer order information to the transshipment so my vehicles can deliver these orders to the customers. To achieve this, I developed the following method in the "on arrival to target location" in the Sprinter:
void sendToTransshipment(Order orderFromSprinter, Transshipment transshipment) { transshipment.orderFromSprinter = order; send(order, transshipment);  }
In my Sprinter agent, I have created a variable called order of type Order (agent) and a parameter called transshipment of type Transshipment (agent). Additionally, in the Transshipment agent, I have defined a public variable called orderFromSprinter.
Despite this setup, I get numerous error messages, such as Syntax error on token ‘.’, ‘}’ and it says that my ‘void’ is an invalid type for the variable sendToTransshipment.
Could someone please help me understand why my code is not working and whether my approach is correct?
Thank you in advanced!

"I am encountering numerous error messages" - Yet you haven't provided a single one. Please have a look at [ask] and keep in mind a question should focus on one problem at the time

you cannot create functions inside the action field
Instead use a function that you can find in the Agent palette and execute that function in the action field.

Thank you for your help! I created a function using the agent palette, but I still receive the error message "void is an invalid type for the variable sendOrderToTransshipment". I read in another post that this problem might be caused by defining a method inside another method. Is that the case? If so, how can I fix it? I'm having trouble understanding the problem.

you created the function wrong... take a java course at noorjax.teachable.com
